# Weird Error: AbstractController::ActionNotFound - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Okay y'all, here goes!

The error is:

> AbstractController::ActionNotFound at /venues/1 The action 'update'
>   could not be found for VenuesController

I'm also getting this error for the action 'destroy' in the VenuesController.

Same exact set of update/destroy issues in my GamesController that looks identical.

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 devise_for :users
 resources :events
 resources :venues 
 resources :games

 get "profiles/:id" => "profiles#show", as: :profile
 get "profiles" => "profiles#index"
 get "calendar" => 'profiles#calendar'


 root 'welcome#index'

 get 'about' => 'welcome#about'

 get 'contact' => 'welcome#contact'
end
```

My VenuesController is:

```
class VenuesController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_venue, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
def new
  @venue = Venue.new
end

def show
end

def index
    @v = Venue.all
end

def edit
end

def create
    @venue = Venue.new(venue_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @venue.save
            format.html { redirect_to @venue, notice: 'Venue was successfully created.' }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
          end
        end
    end
end

def update
    respond_to do |format|
        if @venue.update(venue_params)
          format.html { redirect_to @venue, notice: 'Venue was successfully updated.' }
        else
          format.html { render :edit }
        end
    end
end

def destroy
    @venue.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to venues_url, notice: 'Venue was successfully destroyed.' }
    end
end

private

    def venue_params
        params.require(:venue).permit(:name, :address, :phone, :website, :venues_type)
    end
    def set_venue
        @venue = Venue.find(params[:id])
    end
```

My Venue View _form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@venue) do |f| %>
<% if @venue.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@venue.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this venue from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% @venue.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :address %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :address %>
  </div>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :website %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :website %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :venues_type %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :venues_type %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :phone %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :phone, placeholder: "xxx-xxx-xxxx" %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And then my stack:

> Started PATCH "/venues/1" for ::1 at 2016-10-26 11:49:36 -0400
>
> AbstractController::ActionNotFound - The action 'update' could not be
>   found for VenuesController:   actionpack (5.0.0.1)
>   lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'   actionview
>   (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in`process'   actionpack
>   (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
>
>   actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in`dispatch' 
>   actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in
>   `dispatch'   actionpack (5.0.0.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in`serve'   actionpack
>   (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
>   actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in`
>   each'   actionpack (5.0.0.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'   actionpack
>   (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:725:in`call'
>   warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'   warden
>   (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in`catch'   warden (1.2.6)
>   lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'   rack (2.0.1)
>   lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in`call'   rack (2.0.1)
>   lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'   rack (2.0.1)
>   lib/rack/head.rb:12:in`call'   rack (2.0.1)
>   lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:222:in `context'   rack (2.0.1)
>   lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:216:in`call'   actionpack (5.0.0.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'   activerecord
>   (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:552:in`call'   actionpack
>   (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in
>   call'   activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in`
>   **run_callbacks**'   activesupport (5.0.0.1)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
>
>   activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in`
>   run_callbacks'   actionpack (5.0.0.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'   actionpack
>   (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in`call'
>   actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in
>   `call'   better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in`
>   protected_app_call'   better_errors (2.1.1)
>   lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
>
>   better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in`call'
>   actionpack (5.0.0.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
>
>   web-console (3.3.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:131:in`call_app'
>   web-console (3.3.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in
>   call'   web-console (3.3.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in`
>   catch'   web-console (3.3.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in
>   `call'   actionpack (5.0.0.1)
>
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in`call'
>   railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
>
>   railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in`block in call'
>   activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in
>   `block in tagged'   activesupport (5.0.0.1)
>   lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in`tagged'   activesupport
>   (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
>
>   railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in`call'
>   sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in
>   `call'   actionpack (5.0.0.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in`call'   rack
>   (2.0.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'   rack (2.0.1)
>   lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in`call'   activesupport (5.0.0.1)
>   lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in
>   `call'   actionpack (5.0.0.1)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in`call'   actionpack
>   (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
>
>   rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in`call'   railties (5.0.0.1)
>   lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'   puma (3.6.0)
>   lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in`call'   puma (3.6.0)
>   lib/puma/server.rb:578:in `handle_request'   puma (3.6.0)
>   lib/puma/server.rb:415:in`process_client'   puma (3.6.0)
>   lib/puma/server.rb:275:in `block in run'   puma (3.6.0)
>   lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in`call'   puma (3.6.0)
>   lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:116:in `block in spawn_thread'
>
> Started POST "/__better_errors/0c664909e8d5ec43/variables" for ::1 at
>   2016-10-26 11:49:36 -0400

I'm completely stumped -- any ideas/input is much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Venues controller's **create method has an extra `end`**, thus making everything else below it out of the controller. You are actually closing your class after the create method.

So remove one `end` from the create method definition and you are fine.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! I felt like I was going crazy!